# Can't using block inside return() React JSX

Tags: javascript, reactjs, block, jsx

I'm learning React JS, and facing a problem with JSX.
I have a component :

```
class Content extends React.Component {
  render() {
    const array = ["apple", "orange"]
    return (
      {array[0]}
    )
  }
}
```

It throws error `babel.min.js:7 Uncaught SyntaxError: Inline Babel script: Unexpected token, expected ,`

But if I wrapped `{array[0]}` inside `<span>` tag, this works.

```
class Content extends React.Component {
  render() {
    const array = ["apple", "orange"]
    return (
      <span>{array[0]}</span>
    )
  }
}
```

I think my core JavaScript is not good, please help me understand this problem. Thank you.

Comment: This is *not* core JavaScript, it's React's jsx syntax.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is because in the first example you are not returning a valid element.

When you have a component returning something in the render method, what is being returned is a HTML element created by React.createElement.

[Here](http://babeljs.io/repl/#?babili=false&browsers=&build=&builtIns=false&code_lz=MYGwhgzhAEDCD2A7ALgUxdVAPNiAmMASqmMMgHQIC2ADkustAN4BQ00ATunqhwBQBKZm3bRgSCIzAcOYAJ7QAvNADaAIjA0aIVGoA00NfFmIA5roC6I9l2QBXDomh9rogDwQaYRAD4m02TkVAAYLAF83AHpPbx9XAREwljCgA&debug=false&circleciRepo=&evaluate=true&lineWrap=false&presets=react%2Cstage-2&targets=&version=6.26.0) you can see what babel does.

Try to change with the syntax of your first example to see what happens, then i think it will make things clearer for you.

Answer (score 2):

None of the current answers apply in React 16. Returning a string, or even an array of strings, in a `render()` method is perfectly fine. It does not have to be a react component.

Your problem is a misunderstanding of how the JSX transpiler works. All you really need to know is that the JSX transpiler does nothing until it encounters something it can clearly identify as JSX (some `<xml />`). Your first example has no JSX.

JSX is a recursive algorithm that switches back and forth between `JSX` mode and `JavaScript` mode. An `<xml />` tag tells the transpiler to switch into `JSX` mode. When in `JSX` mode, the JSX curly brace syntax (`{echo stuff}`) is used to **switch back to JavaScript mode**.

You are attempting to use the curly brace syntax to switch back to `JavaScript` mode without being in `JSX` mode. Since your first example contains no JSX, the JSX transpiler will pass it on to the rest of the Babel process as-is. The syntax

```
{array[0]}
```

is not valid JavaScript. Babel will think you're trying to declare an object. For that, Babel is expecting either the plain object literal syntax:

```
{ apple: array[0] }
```

or the es6 property value shorthand:

```
{ apple } // assuming `apple` is a variable in scope
```

If you're wanting to render the `0`th element of the array, just use

```
return array[0]
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe because render method can only [render a single root](https://reactjs.org/docs/rendering-elements.html#components-are-just-like-functions)  , all you need to do is to wrap it inisde valid HTML tag , like  so in will be :

```
render() {
    return (<div> {/* any valid js element */}</div>);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The react component render must return a valid HTML, wrapped into a single HTML container tag (e.g. DIV). I guess you should double check how react works.

```
render() {
  return <div>
  </div>
}
```